# What is the set $ C:= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[0, {1\over n}\right[$

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

What is the set $$ C:= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[0, {1\over n}\right[$$

I guess the result will be that $C$ is an empty set, because the upper limit converges to $0$,
as the limit of ${1\over n}$ is $0$. 
$$\left[0, 0\right[ = \emptyset $$

I tried to prove this with the Archimedean property:

Assume $C$ is non-empty:

$$\exists x\in \mathbb{R}: x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[0, {1\over n}\right[ $$ which is equal to $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \left[0, {1\over n}\right[ $$ concluding that $x$ must be positive, therefore $n > 0$ and $x > 0$.
By looking for solutions I found that the following completes the proof by contradiction. $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n < {1\over n} $$
I still don't quite get how the last statement was made and how this applies the Archimedean property.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The set will always contain zero.

Comment: No the result is $\{0\}$

Comment: Why is there no closed brackets? Is it a typo?

Comment: Because the upper limit only converges to 0 and never actually is 0?

Comment: With the open brackets on the right side I mean that the right side is not included in the set. Did you mean that by typo or something else?

Comment: The set $\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ will always contain $0$ for any $n>0$. This is because the interval is closed on the left, and $\frac{1}{n}$ is never equal to zero.

Comment: @ThePirateBay the $[$ means the right end of the interval is open.

Comment: @Dave. I never saw that notation. Usually, such interval is represented as $\left[a,b\right)$, not $[a,b[$. Also, then [my edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2541201/2) is wrong, would you please correct it?

Comment: @ThePirateBay the notation $[a,b[$ is very standard in Europe.

Comment: @ThePirateBay: the notation is also common in India to distinguish from the coordinates notation. But I strongly dislike it. The context makes it clear if $(a, b) $ is an open interval or coordinate of a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $$C: = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right[ = \{0\}$$

**Proof**: Suppose, for the sake of reaching a contradiction, that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right[$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $\epsilon < \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, contradicting the archimedian property of the real numbers. Hence $C$ can't contain any strictly positive real numbers. Clearly, $C$ can contain no negative real numbers (because $C$ is the intersection of positive intervals), and it is also obvious that $C$ contains $0$, since $0 \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right[$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to *calculate* the result.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\subcalch}[1]{\\ \quad & \quad #1 \\ \quad &}
\newcommand{\subcalc}{\quad \begin{aligned} \quad & \\ \bullet \quad & }
\newcommand{\endsubcalc}{\end{aligned} \\ \\ \cdot \quad &}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
%$

Which $\;x\;$ are in this set of yours?  Letting $\;n\;$ range over the positive integers, we have for all $\;x\;$

$$\calc
    x \in \bigcap_n \left[ 0 , \tfrac 1 n \right[
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\bigcap\;$; definition of half-open interval}
    \langle \forall n :: x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; 0 \le x < \tfrac 1 n \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{rightmost part: multiply both sides by $\;n\;$}\hint{-- work towards isolating $\;n\;$}
    \langle \forall n :: x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; 0 \le x \;\land\; n\,x \lt 1 \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{rightmost part: divide both sides by $\;x\;$, special}\hint{case $\;x=0\;$ -- isolating $\;n\;$}
    \langle \forall n :: x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; (x = 0 \;\lor\; (x > 0 \land n \lt \tfrac 1 x)) \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: move all parts that don't have $\;n\;$ out of $\;\forall n\;$}\hint{-- to simplify}
    x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; (x = 0 \;\lor\; (x > 0 \land \langle \forall n :: n \lt \tfrac 1 x \rangle))
\op\equiv\hint{choose, e.g., $\;n := \left\lceil \tfrac 1 x \right\rceil\;$ which is a positive integer}
    x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; (x = 0 \;\lor\; (x > 0 \land \false))
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify}
    x = 0
\endcalc$$

so we've proven
$$
\bigcap_n \left[ 0 , \tfrac 1 n \right[ \;=\; \{0\}
$$

$%
\endgroup
%$

Comment: Isn't this a bit complicated way of proving a trivial result?

Comment: What do you find complicated about this proof? I find this straightforward. The point of this proof is that it _calculates_ the result $\{0\}$, instead of pulling it like a rabbit out of a hat at the beginning. (And the OP tried to use the wrong rabbit $\varnothing$.)  And it calculates with a very direct strategy: expand definitions, and then simplify, here by isolating $n$ and getting rid of $\forall n$.  And finally, this proof style makes it easy to be precise and not miss special cases.

Comment: If you don't feel this as complicated then I think we have different opinions here and I fully respect your opinion. Your approach appears as if it can be programmed into a computer like an algorithm and used to solve problems of this nature.

Comment: I'm still curious to see if there are some facts behind our opinions then. :-) What do you mean by "complicated", exactly? Do you mean 'roundabout'? Is some step difficult to understand? Or do you just mean 'long'? Or perhaps too long compared to what it proves? You say this looks like it could be done by an algorithm (and I think you're right), but with that you seem to be saying my proof is trivial, nor complicated. :-)

Comment: Ok, by complicated I mean your proof is difficult to understand. It requires more effort on part of the reader because of excessive use of logical symbols. To give an analogy, it is very difficult for a layman to understand any legal document because of the nature of jargon and phrases used and most people ask help of lawyers who translate into common everyday language. If a thing can be described in simple language it is accessible to a wider audience. Math should be for enjoyment of masses and not restricted to elite few.

Comment: The question here is also using unnecessary symbolism. Why can't the book just state this as "if a non-negative real number is less than every fraction of the form $1/n$ then it must be $0$". The proof goes like "if it were not $0$ but positive say $x$ then we could always choose $n>1/x$ and this would invalidate the assumption that $x<1/n$."